# Unusual error routing to http://localhost:3000/statics/edit.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, edit

[image]

Guys, im new to rails. i am getting the above error when trying to edit the products.

## Index.html.erb

## Listing the products in home page

```
 <% @products.each do |product| %>
     <li><%=link_to product.name, statics_show_path(prod_id: product.id)%>
     </li>
     <li><%=link_to "Edit", statics_edit_path(product)%></li>
 <% end %>

 <%= link_to "New Product", statics_new_path %>
```

## Statics Controller

```
class StaticsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @products = Product.all
    end

    def new
        @product = Product.new
    end

    def show
        product_value = Product.find(params[:prod_id])
        @product_attribute = ProductAttribute.where(value: product_value.value)
    end

    def create
        @product = Product.new(product_params)
        if @product.save
            redirect_to root_url
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
        if @product.update(product_params)
            render 'root_url'
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    private

        def product_params
            params.require(:product).permit(:name,:value)
        end 
end
```

Please, help me out. Any help is very welcome.

**Routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'statics#index'

  get 'statics/new'

  post 'statics/create'

  get 'statics/show'

  get 'statics/edit'

  put 'statics/update'

  resources :products

  resources :product_attributes
end
```

Comment: Add your routes.rb to the question. You can remove the controller code as it is irrelevant to routing.

Comment: yea, ive added the routes.rb . please check

Comment: @gundergobi post your `rake routes`  result into your question.

Comment: remove all `get 'statics/new'

  post 'statics/create'

  get 'statics/show'

  get 'statics/edit'

  put 'statics/update'` and use `resources :statics` instead of all this

Comment: undefined method `statics_edit_path' for #<#.
<Class:0x0055ae83452ce8>:0x007f9b04362288>. Right now im getting this error

Comment: @gundergobi replace  `<li><%=link_to "Edit", statics_edit_path(product)%>`  with `<li><%=link_to "Edit", edit_static_path(product)%>`

Comment: thanks a ton, i finally got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes do not contain an `id` segment. In Rails flavor REST the show, edit, update and destroy routes are member routes and must contain an id which says which record should be shown / altered.

An immediate fix is to add an id segment.

```
# still smells
get 'statics/new'
post 'statics/create'
get 'statics/:id/show'
get 'statics/:id/edit'
put 'statics/:id/update'
```

But you should be following [the Rails conventions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) and use the HTTP method instead of adding `/create`, `/update` to the path.

```
# Don't really do this - use resources instead
# its just for the sake of the example
get 'statics', to: 'statics#index'
get 'statics/new'
post 'statics', to: 'statics#create'
get 'statics/:id', to: 'statics#show'
get 'statics/:id/edit', to: 'statics#edit'
put 'statics/:id', to: 'statics#update'
```

Better yet is to use the [resources macro](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) that can generate CRUD routes for you:

```
resources :statics
```

Comment: Note that this will pass the id as `params[:id]` and that you should make the relevant changes to the view and controller. If you don't understand how I would recommend you read [the Rails guides article on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

Comment: thanks for the reply, if u dont mind what path name should i use to invoke the edit action.

Comment: `edit_static_path(@product)` - you can see the route names by running `$ rails routes` from a shell.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
get 'statics/:id/edit', to: 'statics#edit'
```

or you can create CRUD route using this

```
resources :statics
```

for more information use [RubyDoc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: yep, i had a confusion with routes. learned something new, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Not a problem 